# Reverse Engineer Code first - no existing database relationships

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-4.1, one-to-many

I am just getting started with Reverse Engineer Code First and I have hit a blocker that I cannot find an answer for.

I have mapped three tables that do not have any relationships set up on the database side.

- **Errors** - columns are ErrorID, ErrorName etc..
- **Users** - columns are UserID, Username etc...
- **ErrorUsers** - columns are ErrorUsersID, ErrorID, UserID

The idea is that an error can have one or more users responsible for it. I want to be able to run queries which will return all Errors with all respective users.

To my Errors class, I have added a property called:

```
public virtual ErrorUser ErrorUsers { get; set; }
```

To my ErrorMap.cs, I have added

```
this.HasRequired(e => e.ErrorUsers)
                .WithMany()
                .HasForeignKey(e => e.ErrorID);
```

However, when I run my query to return all Errors with all respective users, I get the following error:

```
System.Data.Entity.ModelConfiguration.ModelValidationException was unhandled by user code
  Message=One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

    System.Data.Edm.EdmAssociationEnd: : Multiplicity is not valid in Role 'Error_ErrorUsers_Source' in relationship 'Error_ErrorUsers'. Because the Dependent Role refers to the key properties, the upper bound of the multiplicity of the Dependent Role must be ?1?.

  Source=EntityFramework
```

I have been seeking an answer for the last few hours and the only code samples I can find are those which use the visual .edmx style which I am trying to avoid.

Can someone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

I gave up on this one and I recreated the tables with keys and reimported everything